# Is it possible to export returned properties / methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it is possible to export properties and methods returned from an IIFE module in JavaScript - example below:

```
// Combined Projects
const combinedProjects = (() => {

    // Create Combined Project Array
    const combinedArray = [];

    // Active Project
    let activeProject = combinedArray;

    return {
        combinedArray,
        activeProject
    }
});

// Module Exports
export {activeProject};
```

I'm struggling to access the "activeProject" variable when I import it anywhere. I'm wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to without removing it from the module?

Thanks

Comment: There is no IIFE in the code you posted. `combinedProjects` is just a regular function, never called. An IIFE looks like this: `(() => {})()` (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Comment: If you export `combinedProjects`, then when you import it, you can invoke it, which will allow you to access `activeProject`.

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons - I've exported combinedProjects as you mentioned, but am still having difficulty accessing activeProject in another file (following the import). I have tried console logging combinedProjects and can see that it prints, but I cannot console log either "combinedProjects.activeProject" or "activeProject". (I may have misinterpreted what you meant by invoking). Thanks again

Comment: At the moment `combinedProjects` is a function which will return an object with `activeProject`, you would have to do something like `combinedProjects().activeProject` in the file that you import it in - if you only want to run the function once then you can do that by storing the object in a variable `const obj = combinedProjects()` and then using the object `obj.activeProject`, but if you do this I think the answer below is more what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the purpose of doing it this way, but maybe?

```
const combinedProjects = (() => {

    // Create Combined Project Array
    const combinedArray = [];

    // Active Project
    let activeProject = combinedArray;

    return {
        combinedArray,
        activeProject
    }
})();

const {activeProject} = combinedProjects

// Module Exports
export {activeProject};
```